# Do I have to install numpy, spicy again for python3?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy

I have brew install python2 for OsX, then I install numpy, scipy using `pip install`.

I also need python3, so I `brew install python3`, but when I `import numpy` under python3, `import error` occurs.

I known I can fix this by install numpy using `pip3 install numpy`, but do I have to do this? Since I have the package already installed for python2, can I just tell python3 where it is and then use it?

Comment: No, you have to do `pip3 install numpy`, these are different environments.

Comment: check https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy/1.13.1 . Although you install with a same package name, it has individual package files for each python versions as well as platforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you need to install them using pip3 as well as python3.4 bundles pip in along side of python